# Orthogonal decomposition of derivative of a curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, orthogonality

Let $\alpha: I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be a differentiable curve. I'm in the process of proving that $$||\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)|| \leq L(\alpha)_a^b$$ being $L(\alpha)_a^b$ the length of the curve from a to be.

It says in my text book that, if $\alpha(b) \neq 0$ we can separate  $\alpha'$ in $(t, b]$ as follows:

$$
\alpha'= \langle \alpha' , \frac{\alpha}{||\alpha||} \rangle \frac{\alpha}{||\alpha||} + \alpha^\perp
$$

At first i thought of Gram–Schmidt process of orthogonalization but
I don't recognize this decomposition and dont know why this equality holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two vectors $v$ and $w$, with $w\ne0$, then$$v=\left\langle v,\frac w{\|w\|}\right\rangle\frac w{\|w\|}+\left(v-\left\langle v,\frac w{\|w\|}\right\rangle\frac w{\|w\|}\right).$$This equality expresses $v$ as the sum of a vector which is a multiple of $w$ with a vector which is orthogonal to $w$.